# JetPack Compose UI tests to run on azure pipeline

Tags: android, azure-pipelines, jetpack

I have a suite of tests(they need a device to run on or emulator) that uses JetPack Compose UI testing and some navigation hacks to test a
mobile app written in kotlin that uses compose functions.
I want every night the tests to run on a Azure pipeline, could someone explain to me more detailed what tasks to add in order to do that....Want to mention that I have almost 0 experience with setting up azure pipeline

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1

> I want every night the tests to run on a Azure pipeline

You can configure scheduled triggers to run on a schedule defined using cron syntax.

In yaml:

```
schedules:
- cron: string # cron syntax defining a schedule
  displayName: string # friendly name given to a specific schedule
  branches:
    include: [ string ] # which branches the schedule applies to
    exclude: [ string ] # which branches to exclude from the schedule
  always: boolean # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run. The default is false.
  batch: boolean # Whether to run the pipeline if the previously scheduled run is in-progress; the default is false.
  # batch is available in Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 and higher
```

Classic pipeline with the classic editor:

[image]

You can refer this [Configure schedules for pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more details.

#### Question 2

> could someone explain to me more detailed what tasks to add in order to do that?

You can create the Bash task to install and run the emulator.  The emulator starts as a background process and is available in later tasks.

You can also test on Azure-hosted devices. Add [the App Center Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/app-center-test-v1) to test the application in a hosted lab of iOS and Android devices. An [App Center free trial](https://appcenter.ms/) is required, which must later be converted to paid.

You can refer this document [Build, test, & deploy Android apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops) for more details.